# LocalDate.parse does not validate leap years

Tags: java-time, localdate, datetimeformatter

```
DateTimeFormatter formatters = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd");
endDate = LocalDate.parse(endDateString, formatters);
```

Why does the above code not throw exceptions for leap years?
If you give 2023-02-31, no validation error is thrown.

Comment: This is by design and relies on the formatter. To get your expected exception use either no formatter at all, just `LocalDate.parse(endDateString)`, or if you prefer a formatter, then `DateTimeFormatter .ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd") .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRCIT)`.

Comment: It’s in the documentation of [`DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofPattern(java.lang.String)): *The returned formatter ... uses [`SMART`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART) resolver style.* --

Comment: -- Under the link to *`SMART`* we find: *For example, resolving year-month and day-of-month in the ISO calendar system using smart mode will ensure that the day-of-month is from 1 to 31, converting any value beyond the last valid day-of-month to be the last valid day-of-month.*